# In R, is it possible to solve the traveling salesman problem exactly without using Cygwin?

Tags: r, cygwin, solver, traveling-salesman

I am trying to find a solution to a traveling salesman problem (TSP) in R. The "TSP" package gives heuristic and often stochastic solutions unless one uses the external Concorde solver.
However, on Windows the use of Concorde requires a Cygwin installation. I am working on a server which does not allow me to install Cygwin for security reasons. Is it possible to efficiently find TSP solutions in R without relying on the Concorde solver?

Comment: I solved the TSP problem using this link as guidance.  https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/articles/problem-tsp.html

Comment: @YLC, Did you delete your answer because it requires Cygwin, or ... ?  At a glance it looks fine (i.e. not a "link-only" answer)

Comment: You could write your own function and use brute force if your data isn't too large. To give you an idea of the sizes-- if you wanted to find the best route through 10 cities, that's 181,440 unique sets (paths you could take). (For n cities, `(n - 1)!/2` routes exist.)

Comment: @ben-bolker    The deleted answer does not require Cygwin. If you believe the deleted answer is useful, I can bring it back. However, I think the link is very informative on its own. I have a leaflet app that uses the code documented in the link. Maybe I should post that as an answer? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Use library(ompr) to model the problem as a mixed integer linear program (MILP) using the Miller–Tucker–Zemlin (MTZ) formulation.

Use library(ompr.roi) and library(ROI.plugin.glpk) to solve the problem. GLPK (GNU Linear Programming Kit) solves large-scale MILP problems.

Ref: https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/articles/problem-tsp.html

Here's an application that uses leaflet

```
library(leaflet)

city.1 <- c(city='Paris',  lat= 48.8566,  lng=2.3522)
city.2 <- c(city='Saumur',  lat= 47.2600, lng=-0.0769)
city.3 <- c(city='Rennes', lat= 48.1147, lng=-1.6794)
city.4 <- c(city='Caen', lat= 49.1800, lng=-0.3700)
city.5 <- c(city='Rouen', lat= 49.4428,  lng=1.0886)
D <- data.frame(rbind(city.1, city.2, city.3, city.4, city.5))
D$lat <- as.numeric(D$lat)
D$lng <- as.numeric(D$lng)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircles(data=D, lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat, radius=5000, color='red',
             popup=~city, label=~city)
  
path <- TSP(D)
path


# on the map
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircles(data=path, lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat, radius=5000, color='red',
               popup=~city, label=~city) %>%
    addPolylines(data = path, lng = ~lng, lat = ~lat, group = ~group, weight=2)


    
TSP <- function(D) {

  # distance matrix
    library(geosphere)
    D$lat <- as.numeric(D$lat)
    D$lng <- as.numeric(D$lng)
    df <- data.frame(lng= D$lng, lat=D$lat)
    M <- distm(df)


    library(ompr)
    n <- nrow(M) # problem size 
    
    dist_fun <- function(i, j) {
      # a distance extraction function
      vapply(seq_along(i), function(k) M[i[k], j[k]], numeric(1L))
    }
    
    
    model <- MILPModel() %>%
      
      # variable == 1 iff we travel from city i to j
      add_variable(x[i, j], i = 1:n, j = 1:n, type = "integer", lb = 0, ub = 1) %>%
      
      # a helper variable for the MTZ formulation of the tsp
      add_variable(u[i], i = 1:n, lb = 1, ub = n) %>% 
      
      # minimize travel distance
      set_objective(sum_expr(colwise(dist_fun(i, j)) * x[i, j], i = 1:n, j = 1:n), "min") %>%
      
      # you cannot go to the same city
      set_bounds(x[i, i], ub = 0, i = 1:n) %>%
      
      # leave each city
      add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], j = 1:n) == 1, i = 1:n) %>%
      
      # visit each city
      add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], i = 1:n) == 1, j = 1:n) %>%
      
      # ensure no subtours (arc constraints)
      add_constraint(u[i] >= 2, i = 2:n) %>% 
      add_constraint(u[i] - u[j] + 1 <= (n - 1) * (1 - x[i, j]), i = 2:n, j = 2:n)
    
#    model    # builds the model
    
    
  # solve the model
    library(ompr.roi)
    library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
    result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = TRUE))
    
  # extract the solution
    solution <- get_solution(result, x[i, j])
    path <- solution[which(solution$value > 0),]
    
    odd <- function(x) x%%2 != 0;    even <- function(x) x%%2 == 0
    
    from <- 1
    df <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:nrow(path)) {
      to <- path$j[path$i == from]
#      print(paste("from", dest$city[from], " to", dest$city[to]))
      temp <- data.frame(city=D$city[from], lat=D$lat[from], lng=D$lng[from], group="A")
      if (even(i)) temp$group[1] <- "B" 
      df <- rbind(df, temp)
      from <- to
    }
    temp <- data.frame(city=D$city[from], lat=D$lat[from], lng=D$lng[from], group="A")
    if (odd(i)) temp$group[1] <- "B" 
    df <- rbind(df, temp)
    
    return(df)

}
```

Comment: excellent answer. Is there anyway to add an additional constraint? In my case, each city as an associated cost to visit and I need to stay at or under X value in a given period.

Comment: TSP problems typically use a distance matrix as the cost to visit a node. It is a simple matter to use a similar matrix with any cost function. In the code above, substitute the section labeled "distance matrix" with a cost matrix of your choice.   If you have a second objective, i.e. minimize distance AND some other cost, then you would need to enhance the objective function. If your problem has time constraints, the problem becomes more complex and you should post another question in stack overflow.

Comment: I created another question that I'm unable to solve and would like your input if you have time. Here is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581041/scheduling-permutation-combinatorial-optimization-in-r thanks!