# scheduling permutation combinatorial optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-optimization, ompr

I am trying to solve a scheduling problem related to battery output using the ompr r package which allows for mixed integer programming.Essentially, I need to find the maximum output the batteries can generate basesed on when they are activated. In my case the first row battery would be activated first and the 10th row battery would be activated last. If any subsequent batteries are activated after the previous rows' batteries and are offset another according to the Left_Battery and Right_Battery column they will be penalized (lower output). The original data might be too complex so i also added another dataset of just 3 rows for users to try and solve.

```
df<-structure(list(Current_Battery = 1:10, Output = c(184L, 147L, 
245L, 71L, 383L, 146L, 86L, 122L, 164L, 191L), Left_Battery = c(4, 
8, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 5, 10, 1), Right_Battery = c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

##function to penalize prior batteries if Left_Battery or Right_Battery is in a previous "Current_Battery" Column ##(turned on)

function2=function(vec){
  df=cbind(df,vec)%>%arrange(vec)%>%select(-vec)
  df=df%>%group_by(Current_Battery)%>%mutate(left_id=which(df[,1] == Left_Battery),right_id=which(df[,1] == Right_Battery))%>%ungroup()%>%mutate(self=row_number())
  df=df%>%group_by(Current_Battery)%>%mutate(penalty=ifelse(self<left_id & self <right_id,1,
                                            ifelse(self<left_id & self >right_id,.8,
                                                   ifelse(self>left_id & self >right_id,.6,
                                                          ifelse(self>left_id & self <right_id,.8,1)))))%>%
  mutate(Value=penalty*Output)
final=sum(df$Value)
print(final)

}                             

#test 1 simply sort by highest output column
test=df%>%arrange(desc(Output))%>%select(Current_Battery)
test=test$Current_Battery

function2(test)

#test 2 random vector
rand_vec=sample(1:10)
function2(rand_vec)
```

```
##This includes a table showing an output and value for each battery
function2=function(vec){
  df=cbind(df,vec)%>%arrange(vec)%>%select(-vec)
  df=df%>%group_by(Current_Battery)%>%mutate(left_id=which(df[,1] == Left_Battery),right_id=which(df[,1] == Right_Battery))%>%ungroup()%>%mutate(self=row_number())
  df=df%>%group_by(Current_Battery)%>%mutate(penalty=ifelse(self<left_id & self <right_id,1,
                                                            ifelse(self<left_id & self >right_id,.8,
                                                                   ifelse(self>left_id & self >right_id,.6,
                                                                          ifelse(self>left_id & self <right_id,.8,1)))))%>%
    mutate(Value=penalty*Output)
  
  CostPair<<-df%>%select(Current_Battery,Output,penalty,Value)
  final=sum(df$Value)
  print(final)
  
}
```

I've included a simpler table with 3 rows of data and example images of turning on battery 1 first 3 second and 2 last.

```
df=structure(list(Current_Battery = 1:3, Output = c(20, 22, 24), 
    Left_Battery = c(2, 3, 1), Right_Battery = c(3, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

[image: BATTERY1]
[image: BATTERY3]
[image: BATTERY2]

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? I'm not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i'm trying to find the best order of the "Current_Battery" columm which produces the highest output. So if i rearrange the Current Battery column and run the function i would get different results. Id like to know what is the best order for the Current_Battery column that produces the highest output

Comment: i added in two examples at the bottom that show different final values based on simply sorting by highest output and a random vector

Comment: To solve this brute force would require 3,628,800 runs, i.e. library(combinat), length(permn(10)).  Your examples show 2 runs. There is a better way of course.  Can you restructure your function such that you can get a cost (or gain) for each pair of batteries. Your function generates an output for a specific run. If you set up your problem as an ILP or MILP, you will need to do that anyway.

Comment: I ran your code with 1000 samples. The graph is enlightening. You can get a good estimate of the optimal configuration. 
  df2 <- data.frame()
  for ( i in 1:1000 ) {
    rand_vec=sample(1:10)
    value <- function2(rand_vec)
    temp <- data.frame(t(rand_vec), value)
    df2 <- rbind(df2, temp)
  }
  df3 <- df2[order(df2$value),]
  df3[nrow(df3),]
  plot(df3$value)

Comment: thank you for your response YLC,. Is this what you mean by adding a cost/gain for each battery?  ```CostPair<<-df%>%select(Current_Battery,Output,penalty,Value)``` This will output a data.frame with each Battery and its associated Value after penalty (if needed).

Comment: i incorporated this into the question function too

Comment: Are you fully committed to doing this in R?  There are more expressive languages like python that makes this much clearer and easier to develop.

Comment: not committed to R if there is a python solution I would accept that too. I'm just way more experienced with R.

Comment: The left-right penalty mechanism and how if/how it applies over all the batteries isn't clear at all.  You might want to add to your question a small table that shows how the objective is calculated for a particular sequence.  Does not need to be 10 rows, 3 or so might work.

Comment: I added a simpler table (3 rows) and some images that might help with clearing up the penalty mechanism. thanks!

Comment: You've drawn your 3-battery example to be internally consistent with the left-right, but the original data is *not* internally consistent, so that's confusing.  Ex:  in your original data, battery 4 is left of battery 1 per the `left` data, but the `right` data says that battery 7 is right of 4.

Comment: I should rename the batteries so as not to confuse. The names of the batterys are arbitrary. The numeric values of the battery's name are just the relative factor value. Also, the 3 battery example is just made up data to show how the penalty mechanism works.

Comment: Also, i made the name of the batterys integers so it would be easier to build my function that penalizes the output based on when the battery was turned on or off